# Call a function or a program when using the C-function fopen

Tags: c, file, virtual, fopen

I have a situation in C where I would like to call a c-function when calling fopen. This means I would like to have a "virtual file" of some sort. When I use fopen on this "virtual file" I would like to call a function to produce the data in the file.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're on linux, fopencookie is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to call a *function* to produce output. However, you can call another process using `popen()`, which may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: The problem is that I have a third party FTP-server that I have no control of. I simply use a FTP-client to browse files and when I get a specific file, I would like to create the data dynamically. Maybe there is a feature for this in the ttp-server...

Comment: Some FTP servers, perhaps https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html might also have virtual files facilities

Answer (score 1):

In standard C that is not possible, AFAIK,

If you use a system with the GNU [Glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (such as GNU/Linux) you can have [custom streams](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Custom-Streams.html), notably thru `fopencookie`.

Notice that the standard C++ library also provides (its own variant of) streams, and you could have your own.

On GNU/Linux, the kernel enables you also to provide a [file-system in user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) with [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

> This means I would like to have a "virtual file" of some sort. When I
>   use fopen on this "virtual file" I would like to call a function to
>   produce the data in the file.

To do that, you'd need to write your own file system. Lucky for you, other people have done the hard part: take a look at [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net). For example, you *could* write a file system where the "files" are really RSS feeds. You could then use standard file calls to read the data form those feeds.

Now, whether you *should* take this approach is a different question. If you have control of the code that's reading the file, it'd probably be easier to just have it call the appropraite data-providing function than to require installing a custom file system.

Comment: Yes, this was my thought to... I was thinking about mounting some kind of virtual file system that is responsible only for these virtual files. I will have a look at FUSE.